# kendo mvc file auto upload remove icon not showing

Tags: razor, file-upload, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a kendo upload and after the success I am not able to see the remove icon for the uploaded files. I am using Auto upload and can upload multiple upload. Can any one help me to set the Remove button and is there any way I can customize the icon. Following is the code I have used and the UI for reference.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  .Name("files")
  .Multiple(true)
  .Messages(m => m.Select("Upload Documents +"))
  .ShowFileList(true)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" })
  .Async(a => a.Save("Save", "Document").Remove("Remove", "Document")
  .AutoUpload(true)).Events(e => e.Cancel("onCancel")))
```

UI:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxYSj.png)

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: It is most probably some custom CSS issue because with the latest version in the [Kendo demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/async) the remove icon is shown correctly.

Comment: Plamen Zdravkov : Is there any way I can find the CSS which is causing this Issue.